# ¿Es necesario dividir responsabilidades de un controller en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy creando un ABM con AngularJS, tengo un controlador `usuario.controller.js` que tiene la responsabilidad de crear, eliminar y mostrar el listado de usuarios. El problema es que cada vez que cargo la vista *crear* se vuelve a instanciar el controlador y vuelve a pedir la lista de usuarios.

Es decir, se hace la petición de la lista de usuarios en la vista listado y en la vista crear. Las estoy cargando dinámicamente usando [ui-router](/questions/tagged/ui-router)

¿Es necesario crear un controller `usuario.crear.controller.js` y otro `usuario.listado.controller.js`?

¿Que diseño se suele usar para este tipo de situaciones?

Comment: Es mucho mejor si haces la petición y manejas los datos con un servicio. Hay diferentes formas de sincronizar los datos desde tu servicio con el controlador. Es mejor por dos razones, primero separacion de concerns, el servicio lo puedes reusar muchas veces en muchos controladores o componentes, pero si tienes la peticion en el controlador no vas a poder acceder a ella de forma normal desde otros lugares en la aplicacion, y segundo evitas esas peticiones adicionales cuando cambias de ruta.

Comment: Tengo un service para las peticiones, que devuelve los promises correspondientes y uso lo que necesito de ese service en un controlador, no se si me explico... La cuestión es que tengo un controlador Usuario donde obtengo la lista de usuarios, pero también edita y crea usuarios. Entonces si cargo la vista editar con ese controlador, me trae la lista de usuarios nuevamente, es decir que hace un GET de la lista cada vez que instancio ese controlador.

Comment: Sin ver tu código es difícil, pero me imagino que estás cargando todos los usuarios sin esperar a un evento o algo, podrias usar ng-init en vez de cargarlo siempre, o poner un if para ver si ya cargaron antes de intentar cargar otra vez.

Answer (score 2):

Si no te importa sacrificar un poco la fidelidad de los datos en la lista (por que no se actualizan tan a menudo) el servicio `$http` de Angular tiene una cache interna.

La utilizas así.

```
$http.get("/usuarios", { cache: true } ).then(function(response) { ... });
```

Utilizando la cache, la diferencia entre utilizar uno o varios controladores cambia otros aspectos del sistema (como el mantenimiento) pero no el acceso a los datos, por que has delegado la responsabilidad a otro componente. *El diseño que se suele usar*... varía de un sistema a otro. Por ejemplo: Si estas hablando de una lista de emergencias medicas, esta solución no serviría.

Ya que en tu pregunta, no has dicho como accedes a los datos, si estas utilizando [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), también puedes usar la cache

```
// defines el $resource
var listaLocalDeUsuarios;
var Usuarios = $resource('/usuarios/:id', {}, { 
   lista: { method:'GET', isArray: true, cache: true }
});
Usuarios.lista(function(listado) { listaLocalDeUsuarios = listado });
```

Comment: No se si me conviene usar cache en este caso donde la lista va a cambiar a menudo. Estoy usando un service para acceder a una API REST. Respecto al diseño, me refería a si es mejor separar la responsabilidad de crear aparte o escribir algunas líneas extra para verificar si tiene que traer la lista de usuarios o no, sino cada vista con el controlador usuario pide por la lista cada vez que se instancia.

Answer (score 2):

Si, lo mejor es que tengas un controlador por componente, si quieres mostrar varios usuarios en una tabla puedes hacer una tabla con la lista de usuarios, si quieres editar un usuario puedes hacer un componente que sea un form de usuario que solo requiera hacer la petición de un usuario y no toda la lista. De esta manera ahorras llamadas no necesarias al servidor y tus componentes son re utilizables.

Answer (score 0):

El controlador solo debe ser usado para interactuar con los componentes de interfaz de usuario del componente en cuestión, es decir, es el API que se declara para las funcionalidades, pinchar un botón, ordenar una lista, abrir un dialogo, etc.

Para el caso que describes se debe utilizar el "service", quien es el encargado de almacenar el modelo de datos y declarar las operaciones, consumo de servicios, logica de negocios. El service por ser singleton se ejecutara una vez, manteniendo por tanto el estado de los datos, asi como la ejecucion de operaciones al momento de carga de la aplicacion.

Como ejemlo declaro un servicio:

```
(function(){
  //Las dependencias incluidas en la declaracion del servicio son usadas
  function myService(inyecto, multiples, dependencias, notificacion){
    //Declaro mis funciones, sin preocuparme por la estructura del servicio. De esta manera tenemos un codigo mejor estructurado
    function crear(){
      //Mis operaciones
      //Como resultado de algunas operaciones puedo invocar otros servicios. De esta forma dividimos responsabilidades
      notificacion.notificacionSatisfactoria('Usuario Creado Correctamente')
    }

    function editar(){
      //Mis operaciones
    }

    function consultar(){
      //Mis operaciones
      //Como resultado de las operaciones actualizo el modelo de datos, el cual puede estar en el mismo servicio, o en otro.
      service.usuario = resultadoDeConsulta;
    }

    function eliminar(){
      //Mis operaciones
    }
    //Empaquetamos nuestras operaciones y variables, y las declaramos como publicas. 
    var service = {}
    service.usuario;
    service.crear = crear;
    service.crear = editar;
    service.crear = consultar;
    service.crear = eliminar;
    return service;
}


 //Declaro mi servicio al final del archivo, esto me ayuda a concentrarme en las operaciones.
 angular.module('myApp')
        .service('myService', myService);
//Inyecto las dependencias necesarias para el funcionamiento de mi servicio
myService.$inject = ['inyecto','multiples','dependencias','notificacion'];

 })();
```

En mi controlador me limito a utilizar los servicios, pudiendo reutilziar tanto el controlador, como los servicios, sin el problema del duplicado de las operaciones